# how to iterate through the string and get individual value jsoncpp

Tags: jsoncpp

input of json string as [    {       "description" : "sample"",       "id" : 3,       "name" : "xyz",       "numOfSnapshots" : 132,       "storagePool" : 1,       "volSize" : 32         },]

how to extract the list and get the key and value

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<std::string> keys = json.getMemberNames();
for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = keys.begin(); it != keys.end(); ++it)
{
    if (json[*it].isString())
    {
        std::string value = json[*it].asString();
    }
    else if (json[*it].isInt())
    {
         int value = json[*it].asInt();
    }
    // and so on for each type...
}
```

...If you have [boost](http://www.boost.org/users/download/), you can replace the loop with a very elegant:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(const std::string &key, json.getMemberNames())
```